# Importing an image dynamically in React Component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to dynamically load an image in some React Component. I'm using `require` instead of simply passing the paths in order to improve performance.

I gathered I could use an inline `require` and it does work. However, when I try to pass as a `prop` instead, I get errors.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Turns out both work, I was doing something *else* wrong which was throwing the error. (Bonus question still applies tho)

```
import React from 'react';

// This works
export SomeComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <img src={require(`../images/my-logo.svg`)} />
  </div>
)

// This works too!
export SomeComponent = ({image}) => (
  <div>
    <img src={require(`../images/${image}`)} />
  </div>
)

<SomeComponent image="my-logo.svg" />
```

**Bonus question**: Can this be done with ES6 `import` vs CommonJs `require`?

Comment: Did you create your project with `create-react-app`?

Comment: Nope. I'm actually using GatsbyJS.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it is going to work but you can try:

```
class Image extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { src: null }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadImage(this.props.name)
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.name !== this.props.name) {
      this.loadImage(this.props.name)
    }
  }

  loadImage(name) {
    import(`../images/${name}`)
      .then(image => {
        console.log(image); // this may be object with image inside...
        this.setState({ src: image })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return <img src={this.state.src} />
  }
}
```

Comment: This may work though it seems a little heavy handed.

Comment: that's because of dynamic `imports` use `Promises`.

Answer (score 3):

For React 16+, @Tomasz Mularczyk's answer needs a small tweak:

```
loadImage(name) {
    import(`../images/${name}`)
      .then(image => {
        console.log(image); // This will show an object with a `default` property as the image you imported
        this.setState({ src: image.default })
      })
 }
```

Full Source:

```
class Image extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { src: null }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadImage(this.props.name)
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.name !== this.props.name) {
      this.loadImage(this.props.name)
    }
  }

  loadImage(name) {
    import(`../images/${name}`)
      .then(image => {
        console.log(image); // This will show an object with a `default` property as the image you imported
        this.setState({ src: image.default })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return <img src={this.state.src} />
  }
}
```